# How to change the text color in google-docs based on an range selected from google-sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a google sheets with various cells containing diferent colors, i was able to make a script that replaces a google-docs template with the values from the sheets range, but im not being able to also change the color with it's original when i replace the values.
I was able to capture the colors from the cells but i can't find a way to apply it.

the `setForegroundColor(color);` changes the text color to black only...

The code i have till now:

```
  const template = DriveApp.getFileById('sadfasfadjkg');
  const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('sadfasfadjkg');
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C3:E26');
  const rangeValues = range.getDisplayValues();
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  const today = `${new Date().getDate()}/${new Date().getMonth()+1}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`;
  const copyDoc = template.makeCopy(`Report ${today}`, destination);
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyDoc.getId());
  const body = doc.getBody();

  for (let x = 0; x < rangeValues.length; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < rangeValues[x].length; y++) {
      const cellTxt = richTextValues[x][y];
      const style = cellTxt.getTextStyle();
      const color = style.getForegroundColor();
      
      body.replaceText(`{{${x}-${y}}}`, rangeValues[x][y]).setForegroundColor(color);
    }
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
  const url = doc.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange('J1').setValue(url);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessed your expected result is as follows.

- You want to replace the placeholders in Google Documents with the cell values of Spreadsheet, and also, you want to copy the font color of the cell value.

Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `but im not being able to also change the color with it's original when i replace the values.`, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
```

#### To:

```
const fontColor = range.getFontColorObjects();
```

And, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
const cellTxt = richTextValues[x][y];
const style = cellTxt.getTextStyle();
const color = style.getForegroundColor();

body.replaceText(`{{${x}-${y}}}`, rangeValues[x][y]).setForegroundColor(color);
```

#### To:

```
const forgroundColor = fontColor[x][y].asRgbColor().asHexString().slice(0, 7);
const search = `{{${x}-${y}}}`;
let s = body.findText(search);
while (s) {
  const e = s.getElement();
  const start = s.getStartOffset();
  const text = e.asText().replaceText(search, rangeValues[x][y]);
  text.asText().setForegroundColor(start, start + rangeValues[x][y].length, forgroundColor);
  s = e.findText(search, s);
}
```

- When this modified script is run, each placeholder is replaced with the cell value, and the font color of the cell value is also reflected.

#### References:

- [getFontColorObjects()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolorobjects)
- [setForegroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setforegroundcolorstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-color)

Comment: I get the following error: Exception: Index (19) must be less than the content length (19). when i make the change.

Comment: @Vinicius Oliveira Thank you for replying. About `I get the following error: Exception: Index (19) must be less than the content length (19). when i make the change.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: @Vinicius Oliveira But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script reflecting my proposed modification for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Vinicius Oliveira By the way, I cannot still understand the error line of `I get the following error: Exception: Index (19) must be less than the content length (19). when i make the change.` in my proposed script. I apologize for my poor skill again. Can I ask you where is the error line in my proposed script?

Comment: Somehow i was able to fix it´,, i changed ```const start = s.getStartOffset();``` to ```const start = s.getStartOffset()-1;``` and it just worked, thanks for the help

Comment: @Vinicius Oliveira Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.